# Angular2 app on Azure "You do not have permission to view this directory or page" on sub routes

Tags: angular, azure, iis, angular2-routing

I have published an Angular2 app and deployed it on Azure Web Apps. The application works fine if I start it by browsing to its root:
[http://cafeserver.azurewebsites.net/Web/](http://cafeserver.azurewebsites.net/Web)

However, if I directly browse to a sub route in the application, for example this one:
http://cafeserver.azurewebsites.net/Web/customers

it will throw an error stating "You do not have permission to view this directory or page."

How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to update your `web.config` to redirect all routes to the index page so that Angular routing can kick in. I use the following config for deploying SPAs to Azure:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="SPA">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Note that my setup exempts requests for files, directories and request URIs containing `/api` as I reserve this for backend HTTP routes. You can update yours according to your exemption needs.

Comment: I should just add an important detail. Depending on what server path you have deployed your angular app, you should adjust the url in this line: <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />

Comment: @behroozdalvandi Thanks, that is a good point. The value for url should point to the relative path to where the angular app lives. In my case it's at the root