# Deploying an Angular 13 Universal App in Azure web app service

Tags: azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, angular-universal

I'm trying to deploy an Angular 13 Universal App in Azure web app service using azure devops pipeline but getting below error when trying to access azure webapp.

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Where as I wrote below azure pipeline -

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install -g @angular/cli
  displayName: 'npm install cli'

- script: |
   npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- script: |
    npm run build:ssr --prod
  displayName: 'npm build'
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: 'echo $pwd.Path echo "::set-output name=PWD::$pwd"'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy browser directory from dist directory to the root'
  inputs:
    Contents: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist/app/browser'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/dist/app/browser'


- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy main.js to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/app/server'
    Contents:  main.js
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/dist/app'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveType: zip
    archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
    replaceExistingArchive: true

- upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
  artifact: drop


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'appconnection'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'appwebsite'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

Also tried with this another pipeline which mentioned below -

```
# Node.js with Angular
# Build a Node.js project that uses Angular.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '12.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install @angular/cli -g
  displayName: 'npm install cli'

- script: |
   npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'


- script: |
    npm run build:ssr
  displayName: 'build the projec'


#- task: PowerShell@2
#  inputs:
#    targetType: 'inline'
#    script: 'echo $pwd.Path echo "::set-output name=PWD::$pwd"'

- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy browser directory from dist directory to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'


- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy main.js to the root'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'
    Contents:  main.js
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'

- task: DeleteFiles@1
  displayName: 'Delete the dist/main.js'
  inputs:
    SourceFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'
    Contents: 'main.js'


- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'appconnection'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'appwebsite1'
    deployToSlotOrASE: true
    ResourceGroupName: 'RG-app'
    SlotName: 'production'
    packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'
    WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile server.js -appType node'
    enableCustomDeployment: true
    DeploymentType: 'webDeploy'
    RemoveAdditionalFilesFlag: true
```

Where both pipeline are running successfully but web app is not accessible from any of them, Any suggestion here what exactly I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Specify the default document in Azure Web App Configuration settings.

Comment: It is already added.... let me know if still some changes is required.

Comment: Which file/form is added in default document ?

Comment: Does your App contains `web.config' if not add the `web.config` file with the below snippet

Comment: Please refer [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46182865)

Comment: Default document  has all possible below entry - 
Default.htm
Default.html
Default.asp
index.htm
index.html
iisstart.htm
default.aspx
index.php

and yes, my web has web.config file.

Comment: Check in the KUDU console, whether the referred default document is present in `wwwroot` folder or not.

Comment: looks there some things is not right my wwwroot folder has below structure - 

Dist  --> app --> this has two folder browser and server. where as browser has index.html and server has main.js
web.config is in wwwroot directory.

Comment: Check whether index.html is in default document list

Comment: Delete all the default document list and add only index.html and check once

Comment: tried deleting all other entry and now only index.html is in default document list but  this time getting [http 404 error]

Comment: Add virtual directory path / in portal under configuration => path mappings

Comment: it is already added as mentioned below 

VirtualPath => /, 
PhysicalPath => site\wwwroot, 
TYPE => Application

Comment: Thanks @HarshithaVeeramalla-MT....all good now, there was a directory structure issue in azure pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right Answer is as below -

- virtual directory path / in portal under configuration => path mappings is already corrected. There was no change.
- we changed directory structure for dist directory in azure pipeline in `CopyFiles@2` task like this -

> SourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/dist'
> TargetFolder:'$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app/dist'

and below changes for WebConfigParameters in `AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4` task

> packageForLinux: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/app'

> WebConfigParameters: '-Handler iisnode -NodeStartFile dist/actual_build_app_directory/server/main.js -appType node'

Comment: Can you show your final pipline file. Tanks

Answer (score 1):

> You do not have permission to view this directory or page.

Posting our discussion as an answer , so that it will be helpful for other community members.

- Verify that all the folders are deployed.
- Make sure the folders/ files/directory structure is in correct format.
- `web.config` must be in the root directory.
- Check whether the specified default document is there in the deployed folder structure.
- Add virtual directory path `/` in portal under configuration => path mappings